# Using REST API to decouple database from other REST APIs

Tags: java, spring, database, rest, api

I had some trouble wording the question, but basically, I have found it common, where I work, to create a Java Spring Rest API that connects to a database and a front end application uses that API (web-app -> service API -> database). This couples the application service api to the data store and is often specific use case for the front end application. I see many service APIs creating the same get calls to the same database. This seems wrong to me.

I believe it would be better to create an API for the database itself, then run the service API to that. (web-app -> service API -> datastore API -> database). This would allow all services to access the database without coupling to it directly and having to manage access to that database for 30 applications. It would also allow any application that doesn't need anything other than the data to just use the existing datastore API. I remember an article about how Amazon requires an API for every data store and this is how I would see that being handled.

Is the idea of having a data store API and connecting to that using a service API the right mindset? Or is there some other way I should be handling this?

Comment: It is good to decouple but it would depend on your details. I think it will be introduce complexity to put in one more API ("glue"). If you expose your data via a Rest API together with some API key then shouldn't that be good enough? One more API is one more thing that can go wrong.... You might want to put in another API without forcing everyone to use it though. It is architectural decision for the architect.

Comment: For background: we have a system with albers coordinates. Instead of converting to gps every time for each asset we access, there are 4 projects each taking the coordinates for every object they need access to (such as all computers or all routers) and storing them with gps coordinates in the database for their application. Would it not be better to have an api to access that database with an option to retrieve as gps? this way it can be pulled when needed instead of stored 4 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading what you just wrote it seems to me that what you have is a "microservices done wrong", as I can understand you have a few applications accessing the same database/datastore, from a microservices perspective it's wrong.

Each application should have its own database split in boundaries if any application needs to query/update the other's application data it uses an API rather than accessing the database directly.

The bottom line is, instead of having an API to access a single database each application should limit itself to its own boundaries and access its own database.

Of course, one size doesn't fit all but I do belive it's a good guideline.

Comment: I thought duplication of data was bad. Wouldn't having 4 data stores with the same data be a waste? For instance, we have a list of devices in use by the company. Why would we want 4 duplicates of that list? We would need the source db to feed all of them wouldn't we?

Comment: I think you misunderstood it, I never meant to have the data all duplicated but to have it split in boundaries, each application is responsible for its boundaries and that's it. If another application needs this data you request that to the application you never access its database directly.